# Get data from javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
var frequencies = [{id:124,name:'qqq'}, 
                  {id:589,name:'www'}, 
                  {id:45,name:'eee'},
                  {id:567,name:'rrr'}];
```

And this array of id:

```
var idArray = [124,45];
```

I need create function that return array of string that contains value of the name that has idArray.

for example, the result according to the arrays above(frequencies and idArray) :

```
var result = var frequencies = ['qqq','eee'];
```

How can I implement this function?

Comment: With code. Where is yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** methods.

```
var res = frequencies
  //filter out object array
  .filter(function(v) {
    return idArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1;
  })
  // generate result arrray  from filtered array
  .map(function(v) {
    return v.name
  });
```

```js
var frequencies = [{
  id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}];

var idArray = [124, 45];

var res = frequencies
  //filter out object array
  .filter(function(v) {
    return idArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1;
  })
  // generate result arrray  from filtered array
  .map(function(v) {
    return v.name
  });

// with ES6 arrow function

//var res = frequencies.filter(v => idArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1).map(v => v.name);


console.log(res);
```

---

The same code with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
var res = frequencies
  .filter(v => idArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1)
  .map(v => v.name);
```

```js
var frequencies = [{
  id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}];

var idArray = [124, 45];

var res = frequencies
  .filter(v => idArray.indexOf(v.id) > -1)
  .map(v => v.name);


console.log(res);
```

---

Or use a simple for loop

```
var res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
  // check the id value present in array 
  // push the name property value if id present in array
  if (idArray.indexOf(frequencies[i].id) > -1) {
    res.push(frequencies[i].name);
  }
}
```

```js
var frequencies = [{
  id: 124,
  name: 'qqq'
}, {
  id: 589,
  name: 'www'
}, {
  id: 45,
  name: 'eee'
}, {
  id: 567,
  name: 'rrr'
}];

var idArray = [124, 45],
  res = [];

for (var i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
  // check the id value present in array 
  // push the name property value if id present in array
  if (idArray.indexOf(frequencies[i].id) > -1) {
    res.push(frequencies[i].name);
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

## ESNEXT code

```
frequencies
  .filter(({id}) => idArray.includes(id))
  .map(({name}) => name)
```